# Trigger animationend before remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I got a div element with class `whatever`:

```
<div class="whatever"></div>
```

And a button with class `animate`:

```
<button class="animate">Animate</button>
```

When the button is clicked it will animate the div for 10 seconds, bouncing, fading, dancing, rotating whatever you like to imagine for this example.

The div will trigger and animationend event when it has finished animating showing an alert.

The complete code:

```
$("button.animate").click(function() {
    $("div.whatever").addClass("animationThatSeemsCool").one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function() {
        alert("Whatever has finished animating!");
    });
});
```

All seems to work fine but now there is another button in town!

It's a button with the class `nukeit`:

```
<button class="nukeit">Wipe whatever out!</button>
```

The button does as the name implies the following:

```
$("button.nukeit").click(function() {
    $("div.whatever").remove();
});
```

Everything still seems fine up till now, but there's a problem D:

When a user presses the `animate` button and presses the `nukeit` button while `whatever` is still animating the animationend event will never be triggered and the alert will never show :(

How to manually trigger the animationend event when `nukeit` is pressed?

**Update:**

Here's a JSFiddle link that does above and tries to trigger the animationend event but it's not working D:

https://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/nyvfLee7/

Comment: can you post a JSFiddle example of your code so I can help you comfortably thanks

Comment: Added a jsfiddle link.

Comment: now wait a few mins

Comment: It's not that simple as you think :P Somehow css animation events are a nightmare xD

Comment: lol so true :D but we should try atleast

Comment: see my answer @searhorsepip lol that was too easy

Comment: No it didn't solve the issue, I wanted to trigger the animation stop event not remove the animation :P

Comment: but you will have to remove animation class so that you can again animate you whatever object

Comment: other wise your code will keep on adding animate class to your whatever object and you can see that in developer tools

Comment: but a complete answer not only helps the one who has asked the question but it help who ever will come after

Comment: ``Keep to the point; the answer should be as brief as possible for a complete answer. Don't write about other things than what the question asked for.``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to force the event to trigger:

```
$("div.whatever").trigger('animationend');
```

In relation to your updated question, you only need to trigger one of the listened to events, so 'animationend', for example.

Comment: I was about to post it. Triggering the `animationend` event will trigger the end event, but you'll need to listen to this event. OP would need modify it's code to have the listener outside the click event function.

Comment: Good point! I think in this case, with a click on animate and a click on nuke, the event handler will be set up already. For the more general case though, you are absolutely right!

Comment: I just tried that but it's not working: https://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/nyvfLee7/

Comment: I was already thinking about $.trigger before but somehow it's not working  :'(

Comment: You only need to trigger one event out of the list. See https://jsfiddle.net/nyvfLee7/3/

Comment: Thanks!!! I was going nuts why it didn't work and not it suddenly seems to make sense :D Can you add the fact that I only need to trigger one out of the list to the answer? Since that's the detail that made the difference ^^

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan An answer does not need to quote the whole question to be complete, only the vital code and an explanation why it works is required and preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove animation class that you added that was quite simple ;)

checkout here

```js
$("button.animate").click(function() {
  $("div.whatever").addClass("animation").one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function() {
    alert("Whatever has finished animating!");
  });
});

$("button.nukeit").click(function() {
  $("div.whatever").removeClass("animation");
  $("div.whatever").trigger('animationend');
});
```

```css
.whatever {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.animation {
  animation: rotate 10s linear 1;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="whatever"></div>
<button class="animate">Animate</button>
<button class="nukeit">Wipe whatever out!</button>
```

Comment: I don't know the animation class hence why I called it ``animationThatSeemsCool`` :/ Anyway it seems that passing multiple events to the trigger instead of one was the issue ^^

Comment: It has also fixed the issue of animating again and again, but in the other answer posted here in that we can only animate once

Comment: Those are issues outside the scope of the question, the question itself was a made up simplified version of the issue so any other issues you might see in the question that have no relation to the problem can be ignored.